# PDO parameterized vs non-parameterized query speed

Tags: php, pdo

I understand from my recent use of PHP-PDO over the last few months that you can do a PREPARE statement and then run the query.  In fact I can see the usefulness of this if I'm going to either SELECT on a complex join, varying the where conditions, a repeated number of times.

Or, similarly, if I was wanting to insert multiple records.

However, if I know I only want to run a statement once, shouldn't I just EXECUTE the query?  I'm basically querying the database twice.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you have any input you need to escape to prevent sql injection.

According to the manual on [`PDO::quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
>   parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
>   injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated
>   queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
>   of the query.

Comment: Come on, don't you see it's complete rubbish written there?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Are you referring to the manual or my answer :-)

Comment: There is not much of your answer. But this thing of " much faster" and "can cache"...

Answer (score 2):

here are the benchmarks: http://jnrbsn.com/2010/06/mysqli-vs-pdo-benchmarks

prepared statements are close to within the margin of error in terms of slowdown and therefore can be considered insignificant for most purposes.